# SVN Move folders from a directory into my svn?

Tags: unix, svn, repository, directory, move

I have a directory. It has one file and one directory it in it. The diretory name changes every week or so.

```
-- Directory
*File-13142 *run.pl

--File-13142
*project1.sh project2.sh project3.sh
```

How would I move project1.sh project2.sh project3.sh into my subversion control ? ( Path sub/File/File-13142/project1.sh ie). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to version control with "svn add" and "svn commit" as normal. Use "svn mv" and "svn commit" instead of just "mv" to rename the directory when it changes names.

Comment: `svn add` works for items that are inside a working copy only AFAIK. The directory tree has to be added via `svn import` first.

Comment: SVN add will create directory trees just fine, as long as you "svn add" a subdirectory of a folder already inside SVN control. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html says "When adding a directory, the default behavior of svn add is to recurse"

Comment: I should say I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that the parent directory here is already under SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing tree is not in a working copy, follow these steps:

1. Use `svn import` to add the tree to Subversion repository,
2. `svn checkout` one level higher than the added tree (this way you get a working copy),
3. Perform changes to file contents and commit them to repository using `svn commit`,
4. If you need to move / copy / rename delete files or folders in the working copy, use corresponding `svn` command-line client commands.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html).